# Scala string that contains at most specified characters

Tags: string, scala

For a collection of characters, for instance

```
val specs = "[a-c,1-3]".r
```

how to determine whether a given string contains any number of such characters and only such characters, namely for instance

```
isValid("a1b", specs)
true

isValid("aaa", specs)
true

isValid("1z", specs)
false

isValid("z", specs)
false
```

Comment: `val isValid = string matches "[a-c1-3]+"` Do I miss something?

Comment: @sschaef formalise this into answer for up-voting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` has a method `matches` that already takes a regex:

```
val isValid = string matches "[a-c1-3]+"
```

Note, the `,` in `[a-c,1-3]` must be removed, because it is not part of a regex-range check.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in Scala are implicitly converted to `StringOps` which makes collection style methods available such as `forall` that makes this straightforward.

```
scala> val specs = List('a','b','c','1','2','3')
specs: List[Char] = List(a, b, c, 1, 2, 3)

scala> "a1b".forall(specs.contains(_))
res4: Boolean = true

scala> "aaa".forall(specs.contains(_))
res5: Boolean = true

scala> "1z".forall(specs.contains(_))
res6: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through the string letter by letter and see if there is one that does not match the regex:

```
  import scala.util.matching._
  val specs = "[a-c,1-3]".r                       //> specs  : scala.util.matching.Regex = [a-c,1-3]

  def isValid(in:String, specs : Regex) = {
    !in.exists( c => specs.findFirstIn(c.toString).isEmpty)
  }                                               //> isValid: (in: String, specs: scala.util.matching.Regex)Boolean

  isValid("a1b",specs)                            //> res16: Boolean = true
  isValid("aaa",specs)                            //> res17: Boolean = true
  isValid("1z",specs)                             //> res18: Boolean = false
  isValid("z",specs)                              //> res19: Boolean = false
```

**Edit**  Combining @Brian's better answer about forall with mine that works for regex:

```
  def isValid(in:String, specs : Regex) = {
    //!in.exists( c => specs.findFirstIn(c.toString).isEmpty)
    in.forall(c => specs.findFirstIn(c.toString).isDefined)
  }
```